# How to go to a website and wait 10 seconds after that redirect to another website

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I use webbrowser1.Navigate  to launch web pages. I want to launch a website and keep it 10 seconds. after 10 seconds I want to redirect to the another webpage, etc

I use these codes but it shows only 2nd web page..

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox4.Text = textBox3.Text;
    string[] groups = textBox4.Text.Split('\n');

    timer1.Interval = timer1.Interval + 10000;
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/516524655403741");
    timer1.Interval = timer1.Interval + 10000;
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/548734261950831");
}
```

I use the Timer class to wait 10 seconds but it is not working...

I want to launch 2 as I mentioned above. But this codes shows only 2nd webpage after executing..

Can you explain how I need to adapt my method to launch 1st web page and wait 10 seconds and redirect to 2nd web page?

Comment: You should Google how timer actually works. You're using it like `Thread.Sleep()`

Comment: i tried. but i don't know how to use it to webbrowser.navigate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that in Windows Forms code is executed by firing events. You can't *wait* by expecting the code to stop for 10 seconds (and still have a responsive application).

Instead hook up the Tick event of the timer. That will fire every 10 seconds and use a list to hand the Tick event work. I've chosen to use an [IEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep track of the work but you could also use a Queue or an array where you keep track with an index counter.  Your implementation might look like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // the enumerator has a Current, navigate to it
    webBrowser1.Navigate(websites.Current);
    // we stop the timer if there are no more websites
    timer1.Enabled = websites.MoveNext();
}

IEnumerator<string> websites; // this will keep track of the urls to navigate

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set up a list with url's and then get its Enumarator
    websites = new List<string> {
        "https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/516524655403741" ,
        "https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/548734261950831"
    }.GetEnumerator();
    // enable the timer
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    // make sure our enumerator is going
    websites.MoveNext();
}
```

Make sure your Timer.Interval is set to 10,000 from the Form Designer and hook the Tick event to the event handler:

[image]

With a 2 seconds interval this will be your result:

[image]